# react native expo sqlite issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo-sqlite

I am having issue in react native expo project with sqlite in showing some data from other table by using foreign key. I am trying to develop Point of sale app for practice purpose. I am beginner.

I am trying to add products and while adding product, i have to add supplier name as well.so I took supplierId as a foreign key from supplier table. and after adding product i want to show products. Product is showing but supplierId or supplierName is not showing. i can provide github source code as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.